# Backbone (client-side) filter performance problems within collection

Tags: json, backbone.js, filtering, marionette

I'm loading some initial data from the server in a Backbone Collection.
I set up a search input that fires up an AJAX call to the server and returns the parsed JSON at each keyup.

I'd like the search to be on the client side only instead. So far I've set up this code (the function happens on keyup in the #search input):

todos is a backbone.marionette collection

```
$('.content-search').on('keyup', '#search', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var search = $('#search').val().toLowerCase();
    todos.update(initialData.todos);
    var json = todos.toJSON();
    var filteredJSON = filterJSON(json, search);
    dcis.update(filteredJSON);
}

function filterJSON(arr, part) {
    return arr.filter(function(obj) {
        return Object.keys(obj)
            .some(function(k) {
                console.log(obj[k]);
                if(typeof(obj[k]) == 'string'){
                    return obj[k].toLowerCase().indexOf(part) !== -1;
                }
            });
    });
};
```

It's awfully slow. It was actually faster to call the server with an AJAX call than do the filtering client-side !

Any ideas why my code is so slow ? The JSON is quite big (500+ entries)

Comment: I'd try not using any of the underscore features for filtering and looping as each requires calling functions (just use `for` loops). You might need to optimize for the text search by lower casing the text once, rather than every time it needs to search.

Comment: you may just be including the console.log for your own testing, but that can slow down overall performance if its being invoked a lot. also, using a case insensitive RegEx might be faster than toLowerCasing() and index-checking in your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even with 500 entries I guarantee the most work isn't in filtering the JSON. It's in the rendering/paint cycle in the browser unless you're manually updated the DOM instead of using the backbone render function.

Try first setting `console.time('filterMyCollection')` above the line for where you call filterJSON. And `console.timeEnd('filterMyCollection')` after it.

Then do the same but at as the first line in the backbone render function and timeEnd as the last line.

If you're destroying and recreating a template that is a massive load of memory, CPU and garbage collection time. If you need help displaying a lot of elements you should look how it's done in PerfView (https://github.com/puppybits/BackboneJS-PerfView). It's able to scroll through 1,000,000 models in Chrome at 120FPS.